# Is there someway to limit how much rows a join will catch in Spark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

For example:

val joinedTables = dataFrame.join(dataFrame2, dataFrame("key") === dataFrame2("key"))

Supposing that these two are large tables, i want to limit the process of joining because
these tables are too large, and i wanna quicky testes before joining all columns and rows.

I just wanna see like 10 or 20 rows of join.

Answer (score 0):

Just limit before join

```
val joinedTables = dataFrame.limit(20).join(dataFrame2.limit(20), dataFrame("key") === dataFrame2("key"))
```